# Any recommendation of powerful open source javascript dode slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, touch, slideshow, effect

I need a powerful javascript slider like jssor slider, but I need full javascript source code to rewrite it for video support.

The following are outstanding features,

**Touch + Drag navigation on touch device**
When touch and drag the slider with finger on a touch device like iphone (iOS, Android, Windows Surface), the slider will move left/right or up/down.

**Free slideshow/caption animation when touch**
If slideshow or caption animation is running when touch, it will freeze when touch.

**Continue or rollback slideshow/caption animation when release touch**
If slideshow or caption animation is frozen when touch, it will continue or rollback when release touch.

**Realtime responsive, scale smoothly**
When browser window is resized, the slider will scale to exact with of window at real time with no wait, no stop of animation.

**Infinite slideshow effects/transitions**
jssor slider comes with 360+ slideshow effects/transitions

**Infinite caption effects/transitions**
jssor slider comes with 390+ caption effects/transitions

**High performance, maybe a bit less, better up to jssor slider**
jssor slider announced the CPU usage is 1% (slider), 4% (slideshow), 4% (caption animation)

**IE 6 compatible is a plus**
jssor slider announced Chrome 3+, IE 6+, FF 2+, Safari 4+, Opera 10+

Any recommendation?

Answer (score -1):

You can check this one, just released today: [Phantom Touch Slider](https://github.com/Pantherius/phantom-touch-slider-jquery-plugin)

Probably, you need to customize to fully fits to your needs.